# Updating Algolia Index Records On Firestore Update

Tags: firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, algolia

I'm trying to use cloud firestore triggers to automatically update records in our Algolia "users" index.

Here's our cloud function:

```
exports.updateUser = functions.firestore
.document('users/{id}').onUpdate((change, context) => {
    const afterData = change.after.data()
    return algoliaIndex.partialUpdateObjects([{afterData}]).catch((err) => {
    return console.error(new Error(err))
  })
})
```

In our firebase functions logs we see this error:

```
Error: Usage: index.partialUpdateObjects(arrayOfObjects[, callback])
  at Index.partialUpdateObjects (/user_code/node_modules/algoliasearch/src/Index.js:136:11) 
  at exports.updateUser.functions.firestore.document.onUpdate (/user_code/index.js:19:26) 
  at cloudFunctionNewSignature (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/cloud-functions.js:114:23)
  at cloudFunction  (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/cloud-functions.js:144:20)
  at /var/tmp/worker/worker.js:827:24 
  at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:135:7)
```

What are we doing wrong?

Thanks!

EDIT:
I've updated the code below which now works EXCEPT that Algolia requires the Object ID to be passed within the object in order for it to updates the proper record. How can I reference the ObjectID within the "afterData" object?

Answer (score 0):

`partialUpdateObjects` (emphasis object**s**) is expecting `arrayOfObjects` but the data you get from Firestore in `afterData` is an object.

Try wrapping it in an array or better yet, use `partialUpdateObject`.

https://www.algolia.com/doc/api-reference/api-methods/partial-update-objects/?language=javascript

Comment: This helps and I'm getting closer... I now I need to somehow include the Object ID

Comment: @GregFielding `[{ ...afterData, objectID: <your object id> }]`

Comment: thanks imjared.... firebase isn't letting me deploy with the ... in front of afterData.

Comment: Is there another way to write this? return algoliaIndex.partialUpdateObjects([{ ...afterData, objectID: afterData.id }])

Comment: `let data = afterData; data.objectID  = <your-object-id>; algoliaIndex.partialUpdateObjects([ afterData ]);`

Answer (score 0):

The objectId is stored inside of the `context`, which holds the `params` attribute. So somewhere inside of your `onUpdate` method, you should declare the variable such as the following:

```
const objectId = context.params.*insert the key you're using*
```

If you're unsure what the name of your key is, you can use `console.log(context.params)`, deploy your changes to the Firebase cloud, and then see what is printed out in the Functions logs when you try editing a document.